# Как убрать ask в конце URL?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Как убрать ask в конце URL ?

на данный момент открывается на такой адрес site.com/login/question/140/ask

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а как сделать чтоб открывалось на такой адрес site.com/login/question/140

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте настроить файл `.htaccess`. Например

```
Redirect 301 site.com/login/question/140/ask site.com/login/question/140/
```

Comment: Думаю, что лучше выянить причину его (`ask`'а) появления и устранить её, если конечно он не играет роль ...